# Screen Videoing on the iPod Touch?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I want to record a Screen Video of the iPod Touch 4G. Unfortunately, The iPod Touch doesn't have apps like SnapzPro or screenflow. I did find a iShowU but its not the screen recording one.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no easy way to do this on the device itself.  I believe the most common approach is to use a desktop screen recording app in conjunction with the iPhone simulator.

There's an app called SimFinger for the desktop that can help make screencasts recorded in the simulator look a bit nicer.  Details: http://blog.atebits.com/2009/03/not-your-average-iphone-screencast/

Answer (score 0):

There is a way if your device is jailbroken. BTW, Jailbreaking is now legal in the US. To jailbreak, go here: www.greenpois0n.com Anyway, there is an app in cydia(the jailbroken app store) called "Screen Recorder." After you press play, it will record everything you do until you hit stop.
Hope this helps
-CodeKid1001